# Multiple divs span height of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is a good way to get multiple divs to span the height of their parent containing div which as a **fixed height**?

Please see diagram below:

[image]

Here is the proposed markup:

```
<div class="parent">

   <div class="child"> div1 </div>

   <div class="child"> div2 </div>

   <div class="child"> div3 </div>

</div>
```

The child divs should always fill the entire height of parent div, despite how many of them there are but their height DOES NOT need to be equal and should change based on their content.

So if one has alot of content it would be larger and the rest would adjust accordingly.

I have done this using a table but figured there may be some simple way to do using just divs, which would be advantagous since they are more versatile for responsive layouts.

Is there a pure CSS solution to this?

Comment: The parent `<div>` has a fixed `height`? If not, that's exactly what they currently do.

Comment: oh, yes.. parent div has a fixed height. sorry, going to add that to the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you have this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  background-color: peachpuff;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.child:first-child {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
.child:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.child:last-child {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    Proin ac lacus pharetra, vestibulum enim in, pellentesque metus. Curabitur fringilla facilisis pretium. Vivamus eu sapien id eros interdum ultrices et a turpis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc odio leo, accumsan in ipsum eu, porttitor ornare sapien.
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ac lacus pharetra, vestibulum enim in, pellentesque metus. Curabitur fringilla facilisis pretium. Vivamus eu sapien id eros interdum ultrices et a turpis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
    torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
  </div>

</div>
```

---

To achieve the requirement, you can use flexbox.

In your parent element use:

- `display: flex;` to make it a flex-container.
- `flex-direction: column;` to change the main-axis.

In your children elements use:

- `flex: 1;` To distribute the free space among flex-items.

> **flex: `<positive-number>`** Equivalent to `flex: <positive-number> 1 0`.
>   Makes the flex item flexible and sets the flex basis to zero,
>   resulting in an item that receives the specified proportion of the
>   free space in the flex container. If all items in the flex container
>   use this pattern, their sizes will be proportional to the specified
>   flex factor.

*Source [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex).*

---

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  background-color: peachpuff;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.child {
  flex: 1;
}
.child:first-child {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
.child:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.child:last-child {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    Proin ac lacus pharetra, vestibulum enim in, pellentesque metus. Curabitur fringilla facilisis pretium. Vivamus eu sapien id eros interdum ultrices et a turpis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
    Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc odio leo, accumsan in ipsum eu, porttitor ornare sapien.
  </div>

  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ac lacus pharetra, vestibulum enim in, pellentesque metus. Curabitur fringilla facilisis pretium. Vivamus eu sapien id eros interdum ultrices et a turpis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
    torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
  </div>

</div>
```

---

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/epsvq9yj/)

Answer (score 3):

You should investigate Flexbox (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

In this case you would add:

```
.parent { display:flex; flex-direction: column; }
.child { flex-grow:1; }
```

Flex-Direction: "This establishes the main-axis, thus defining the direction flex items are placed in the flex container."

Flex-Grow: "If all items have flex-grow set to 1, the remaining space in the container will be distributed equally to all children. "

Comment: Ive used flex box a bit in the past to force a single div to the height of it's parent but have not looked into it too much deeper. thank you for the great reference! would you happen to know the support specs for flexbox?

Answer (score 1):

`flex: 1;` will help keep elements even with parent containers. It can get really tricky so brush up on some flexbox info.

My favourite quick reference guide I know of for flexbox is at [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Always be sure to test final code on IE, as usual IE sucks at displaying things how you'd expect them to display.

Here's a quick demo incorporating an uneven element on the left side to show how flexbox can work with different sizes. Includes a few annotations in the code to help understand the basics of what's going on.

Resize screen to see responsiveness. (view full screen or use the fiddle, the mini previewer here doesn't seem to like my use of vertical height (vh))

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* stack elements within on top of each other as opposed to row */
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
}
.left-block {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1; /* make element grow */
  justify-content: center;  /* horizontal align content */
  align-items: center; /* vertical align content */
}
.left-block:nth-child(1) { background-color: hsla(50, 20%, 50%, 1); }
.left-block:nth-child(2) { 
  background-color: hsla(150, 20%, 50%, 1);
  padding: 100px 0px; /* padding added to left two to deomonstrate an unevenly sized block */
}
.left-block:nth-child(3) { background-color: hsla(200, 20%, 50%, 1); }
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: hsla(300, 20%, 60%, 1);
}
.right-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-block">left one</div>
    <div class="left-block">left two</div>
    <div class="left-block">left three</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-block">
      righty
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/m1r4z8b5/